# same xml file names in different layout folders issue(android)

Tags: android, xml, layout

i was trying to work with different  screen resolutions.Then from some internet resource i came to know that i have to specify some folders in my res folder as layout-small,layout-large etc. like that and then to save my all corresponding .xml files in these folders with the same names.However when i was trying to work with this in eclipse,A dialogue box came up saying that do you want to overwrite the existing file.
i.e it is not letting me save the .xml file in the corresponding folders with the same name.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
```

how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I think you are trying to copy same file same folder..?

Comment: Try Cleaning the project and check if folder is containing any my_layout.xml file or not. There must be such a file, thats why it is give that error.

Comment: @shylendra: no,i have specified what i was trying to do in the directory hierarchy above

Comment: https://github.com/ddewaele/AndroidTwitterSample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the same issue.Creating xml file with the same name even in different folders of layout folders  (like landscape layouts in layout-land and portrait layout in general layout folders),but eclipse was not letting me to create these files. Fortunately i came to my own rescue to perform the task as is desired by you.I just copy pasted the same file from of the folder to the other and then manually opening each of the file and changing their contents one by one.Eclipse will allow you to create a xml file  even if it is located in the different layout folder.(MAY BE A BUG).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment to your question, So i put it here.

- " i came to know that i have to specify some folders in my res/layout folder as layout-small,layout-large etc."

You should create layout, layout-small, layout-large folders directly inside the "res" folder. Not in the "res/layout" folder.

- Go to the project directory in the explorer and copy & paste the xml file directly in to those folders and check them in eclipse

Comment: i have mentioned the directory hierarchy in my question...and already they are under res directory

Comment: @bayatreex Yes, the hierarchy you put in the code section is correct. Bute the directory hierarchy you mentioned in the paragraph is wrong (some folders in my res/layout folder).

Answer (score 0):

It will never allow you to save file in same name. Use different folder for different size. use drawable folder alone for one size and use Hdpi,ldpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi for different size of screens.

Comment: I think you have check this before gave ans :http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html